# Slack alerts for oozie job status alerting

Tags: slack-api, oozie-workflow

I am looking to change the existing system of alerting for oozie job statuses from email, to slack alerts.

I haven't found resources online.
The existing method is using: `<email xmlns="uri:oozie:email-action:0.1">`

Answer (score 0):

Slack provides [integrations with Webhooks](https://api.slack.com/messaging/webhooks) which is one solution to alerting using slack. You may have to write your custom REST API producer which will POST messages to the webhook and those will get populated in designated channel.

Alternatively, there is solution using [Email app](https://bellnetwork.slack.com/apps/A0F81496D-email?tab=more_info) which uses slack provided emails which you can use in existing oozie email alerts. When an email is sent to this email address, this will be redirected to corresponding person or channel in Slack app.